# Basic JavaScript crashes website

Tags: javascript

Im having problems finishing the codeavengers practice tutorial
when i run this code it just crashes, any idea why?

The purpose is to count how many teenagers from the range of 13-19

```
    var age1 = prompt('Please insert your age');
    var age2 = prompt('Please insert your age');
    var count = 0;
    if (age1 > 12 && age1 < 20 || age2 > 12 && age2 < 20) {
    count = count + 1;
    }
    alert(count);
```

Comment: Depending on what ages you type in, that could be an endless loop. Did you mean to make that an `if` statement instead of a `while` loop?

Comment: Its just a basic code to count how many teenagers, sorry about that, should've added more information

Answer (score -1):

there is nothing that will stop the while loop!   age1 and age2 are static values that are never changing.  Also don't forget the semicolins on lines 1 and 2

Comment: So what would should i use?